# Which is faster (ISNULL(@SKU, '') = '') or (@SKU IS NULL OR @SKU = '')

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures

There is one if case where I am using `IF @SKU IS NULL OR @SKU = ''`, but my friend says it will take more time as compare to `IF ISNULL(@SKU, '') = ''`. So you should use `IF ISNULL(@SKU, '') = ''`. But I think I'm using correct. So please suggest me which one is run faster.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_GetExistingRefunds  
(  
  @OrderNo VARCHAR(50),  
  @SKU VARCHAR(255),   
  @ProfileID INT   
)  
AS   
BEGIN    
  --IF ISNULL(@SKU, '') = '' --this work faster or 
  IF @SKU IS NULL OR @SKU = '' --this work faster 
  BEGIN 
    SELECT OrderNo, SKU, ISNULL(Quantity, 0) Quantity, ISNULL(Amount, 0) Amount  
    FROM StoreRefundOrder SRO   
    INNER JOIN StoreRefundOrderItem SROI ON SRO.ID = SROI.RefundOrderID   
    WHERE SRO.OrderNo = @OrderNo    
    AND ProfileID = @ProfileID    
  END 
  ELSE
  BEGIN 
    SELECT OrderNo, SKU, ISNULL(SUM(Quantity), 0) Quantity, ISNULL(SUM(Amount), 0) Amount  
    FROM StoreRefundOrder SRO   
    INNER JOIN StoreRefundOrderItem SROI ON SRO.ID = SROI.RefundOrderID   
    WHERE SRO.OrderNo = @OrderNo   
    AND SROI.SKU = @SKU  
    AND ProfileID = @ProfileID   
    GROUP BY OrderNo, SKU   
  END    
END
```

Comment: even if there is any different in performance, i doubt it is significant

Comment: @DaleK, you are right i just miss it. thanx

Comment: In the great scheme of database performance this is such a trivial situation as to not be worth spending any time on. There are far more impactful issues which you will come across.

Comment: As an example, its recommended to always schema preface your objects e.g. instead of `FROM StoreRefundOrder SRO` use `FROM dbo.StoreRefundOrder SRO` (assuming your scheme is `dbo`).

Comment: Have you started your analysis with the _actual execution plan_ to ensure that you are not engaged in [premature optimization](http://xkcd.com/1691/)? Do you know where the bottlenecks are? (See [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).)

Answer (score 1):

***In the context of an IF/ELSE Procedural batch***

It doesn't make any difference whatsoever. It literally takes 0.00 MS to determine if a value is blank or unknown, it takes the 0.00MS to determine if  `ISNULL(@SKU, '') = ''`. If there is a difference it would likely be measured in nanoseconds IMO. Again, *this in the context of a procedural batch* because the statement is only being evaluated once.

***In the context of an FILTER (e.g. ON, WHERE or HAVING CLAUSE)***

Here the difference is actually enormous, it cannot be understated. This is tricky to explain with parameters and variables involved, so, for brevity, I show you an example with this sample data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#things','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #things;

SELECT TOP (10000) Txt = SUBSTRING(LEFT(NEWID(),36),1,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%x.N))
INTO   #things 
FROM       (VALUES(1),(30),(40),(NULL)) AS x(N)
CROSS JOIN sys. all_columns;

UPDATE #things SET Txt = NEWID() WHERE txt = '0';

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc_things1 ON #things(Txt);
```

The following queries will find rows that either do or do not contain blanks or nulls

```
-- Finding things that are blank or NULL
SELECT t.Txt
FROM   #things AS t
WHERE  t.Txt IS NULL OR t.Txt = '';

-- Finding things that are NOT blank or NULL
SELECT t.Txt
FROM   #things AS t
WHERE  NOT(t.Txt IS NULL OR t.Txt = '');

SELECT t.Txt
FROM   #things AS t
WHERE  t.Txt > '';

-- Finding things that are blank or NULL
SELECT t.Txt
FROM   #things AS t
WHERE  ISNULL(t.Txt,'') = '';

-- Finding things that are NOT blank or NULL
SELECT t.Txt
FROM   #things AS t
WHERE  ISNULL(t.Txt,'') <> '';
```

The first three queries are SARGable, the last two are not because of ISNULL. Even though there's an index to help me, the ISNULL renders it useless here. It's the difference between asking someone to look in a phone book for everyone whose name *begins* with "A" and finding everyone who's name ends with "A".

SARGable predicates allow a query to seek a portion of an index where non-SARGable predicates force a query to scan the *entire table* REGARDLESS of the how many matching rows exist (if any). When you are dealing with millions/billions of rows joined to many other tables the difference can be a query that runs in seconds to one that, in some cases, may run for hours or even weeks (I've seen a few).

**EXECUTION PLANS:**

[image]

Note that this last one `WHERE  t.Txt > ''` will work too. Any non-null text value is `> ''` and if t.Txt was NULL then it will also evaluate to false. I include this because this expression works for filtered indexes. The only catch is you can't use it on a text field where Implicit conversion can transform this into the number 0 or less. Note these queries:

```
IF '' =   0  PRINT 'True' ELSE PRINT 'False'; -- Returns True
IF '' =  '0' PRINT 'True' ELSE PRINT 'False'; -- Returns False
IF '' >  -1  PRINT 'True' ELSE PRINT 'False'; -- Returns True
IF '' > '-1' PRINT 'True' ELSE PRINT 'False'; -- Returns False
```

Answer (score 0):

`IF @SKU IS NULL OR @SKU =''` is checking null and blank both. In second case `if Isnull(@sku,'')` you are checking null and assigning '' for null value. Both are different cases.

Comment: OP has already said that missing `''` is a typo. And you're not addressing the performance - which is the question!

Answer (score 0):

> Which is faster `(ISNULL(@SKU, '') = '')` or `(@SKU IS NULL OR @SKU =
>   '')`

It really doesn't matter in this case. If you were comparing against a column then `(SKU IS NULL OR SKU = '')` would be preferable as it can use an index but any difference for a single comparison against a variable will be in the order of microseconds and dwarfed by the execution times of the `SELECT` statements.

To simplify the `IF` statement I'd probably invert it anyway as below

```
  IF @SKU <> '' --Not null or empty string
  BEGIN 
    SELECT OrderNo, SKU, ISNULL(SUM(Quantity), 0) Quantity, ISNULL(SUM(Amount), 0) Amount  
    FROM StoreRefundOrder SRO   
    INNER JOIN StoreRefundOrderItem SROI ON SRO.ID = SROI.RefundOrderID   
    WHERE SRO.OrderNo = @OrderNo   
    AND SROI.SKU = @SKU  
    AND ProfileID = @ProfileID   
    GROUP BY OrderNo, SKU  
  END 
  ELSE
  BEGIN 
     SELECT OrderNo, SKU, ISNULL(Quantity, 0) Quantity, ISNULL(Amount, 0) Amount  
    FROM StoreRefundOrder SRO   
    INNER JOIN StoreRefundOrderItem SROI ON SRO.ID = SROI.RefundOrderID   
    WHERE SRO.OrderNo = @OrderNo    
    AND ProfileID = @ProfileID  
  END
```

Comment: This wont work when `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` is used (although it is "soon" to be deprecated)

Comment: @kobik - true but I would strongly advise people not use that option and I don't write my code to cater for it.

Answer (score 0):

A little long for a comment.

As has been noted by many already, in this case your two options don't really make any appreciable difference. But in the future, when you think of a couple of different ways to code something, there are standard practices you can implement quickly and easily to test for yourself.

At the top of your code block, add this command:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;
```

You can use either `TIME` or `IO`, but I almost always want to see both, so I always turn them both on at the same time.

The output from this addition will show up in your Messages window after your query or queries run and will give you tangible information about which method is faster, or causes less stress on the SQL Server engine.

You'll want to run a few tests with each option. Warm cache / cold cache especially, but a few iterations is best one way or the other to get an average or eliminate outlier results.

I'm weird, so I always close my code block with:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME, IO OFF;
```

But strictly speaking that's unnecessary. I just have a thing about resetting anything I change, just to avoid any possibility of forgetting to reset something that will matter.

Kendra Little has [an informative blog post on using STATISTICS.](https://littlekendra.com/2016/03/24/3-tricks-with-statistics-io-and-statistics-time-in-sql-server/)